# Mapbox Filter is not giving Correct result, when using promoteId

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Good Day,

I have a geojson(similar to below) and I am facing trouble with an expression that works well when used without promoted.

JSFiddle:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/dollysingh3192/w6bzsx84/7/
```

**GeoJson**

```
{
                'type': 'FeatureCollection',
                'features': [
                    {
                        "geometry": {
                            "type": "Point",
                            "coordinates": [
                                8.612079620361328,
                                -2.932969060251523
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "Feature",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": "GMYTEORRGI5DQ",
                            "sid": "s_133",
                            "n": "15",
                            "r": "13",
                            "s": "312",
                            "sz": 5.5,
                            "m": "n",
                            "ri": 13,
                            "si": 7
                        },
                        "id": 11578
                    }
             ]
}
```

**Working**

Below expression is working fine and extract one feature from Map(Without using **promoteId**)

```
mapInstance.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['seat'], filter: ["any", ["==", ["id"], 21762]] });
```

Working GIF:
[image]

**Not Working**

But on using **promoteId** in geojson source, the expression is not working at all.

```
mapInstance.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['seat'], filter: ["any", ["==", ["id"], "GMYTEORRGI5DQ"]] });
```

Not Working GIF:
[image]

However, I noticed that setFilter and setFeatureState work fine with the same expression.

```
mapInstance.setFilter('seat', ["match", ["id"], "GMYTEORRGI5DQ", true, false]); //Works fine
```

GIF with setFilter:(Don't know why it works). [LINK](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8565108/103742294-955ce200-5020-11eb-8137-9776e73c7f45.gif)

Please guide. Am I doing anything wrong here?

https://jsfiddle.net/dollysingh3192/w6bzsx84/7/

Answer (score 1):

To get properties data use `get`

Try it this way

```
mapInstance.queryRenderedFeatures({ 
    layers: ['seat'], 
    filter: ["==", ["get", "id"] ,"GMYTEORRGI5DQ"]
});
```

Update:

To fitler on `id`/`promoteId`

```
        mapInstance.queryRenderedFeatures({ 
          layers: ['seat'],
          filter: ['==', 'id', 'GMYTEORRGI5DQ']
        })
```

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#id

Comment: Thank you for replying. I want to apply query on feature "id" specifically(Not properties). Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I am using the exact expression but no luck. I have added a JsFiddle. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/dollysingh3192/w6bzsx84/7/ where the console statement is empty every time.

Comment: @Dolly try the new syntax without `[` `]` around `id` https://jsfiddle.net/q43roh8e/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just one question why ```[ "id"]``` expression doesn't work with promoteId.  As it set's the id of the feature from the properties object and it should work as if we don't set the promoteId at all.

Comment: @Dolly, Not sure why.  `id` needs to be a whole number first.  It could be that `['id']` is not available at that stage because of `promoteId`.  You can dig more here https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/c7ed000f6d628531e0620df9d141dd6e2237477e/src/style-spec/types.js#L11 to see the `FilterSpecification` and `PromoteIdSpecification`

Comment: I registered a bug on Mapbox GitHub issue's https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/10257, it's a bug and still needs's to be fixed. But thank you for all your helpful responses.